# I am getting internal compiler error

Tags: android, compilation, server, android-jack-and-jill

```
[ 34% 16888/49032] Building with Jack:...l_intermediates/with-
local/classes.dex
FAILED: /bin/bash out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-
all_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex.rsp
java.lang.AssertionError
at com.android.sched.scheduler.MultiWorkersScheduleInstance.process(MultiWorkersScheduleInstance.java:523)
at com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:738)
at com.android.jack.Jack.checkAndRun(Jack.java:412)
at com.android.jack.CommandLine.runJack(CommandLine.java:79)
at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Cli01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Cli01CompilationTaskImpl.java:85)
at com.android.jack.server.tasks.JackTask.handle(JackTask.java:168)
at com.android.jack.server.tasks.SynchronousServiceTask.handle(SynchronousServiceTask.java:49)
at com.android.jack.server.tasks.JackTask.handle(JackTask.java:55)
at com.android.jack.server.router.PathRouter.handle(PathRouter.java:65)
at com.android.jack.server.router.ContentTypeParameterRouter.handle(ContentTypeParameterRouter.java:84)
at com.android.jack.server.router.ContentTypeRouter.handle(ContentTypeRouter.java:82)
at com.android.jack.server.router.ContentTypeRouter.handle(ContentTypeRouter.java:82)
at com.android.jack.server.router.ContentTypeRouter.handle(ContentTypeRouter.java:82)
at com.android.jack.server.router.ContentTypeParameterRouter.handle(ContentTypeParameterRouter.java:84)
at com.android.jack.server.router.ContentTypeRouter.handle(ContentTypeRouter.java:82)
at com.android.jack.server.router.ContentTypeRouter.handle(ContentTypeRouter.java:82)
at com.android.jack.server.router.MethodRouter.handle(MethodRouter.java:67)
at com.android.jack.server.router.RootContainer.handle(RootContainer.java:49)
at org.simpleframework.http.core.RequestDispatcher.dispatch(RequestDispatcher.java:121)
at org.simpleframework.http.core.RequestDispatcher.run(RequestDispatcher.java:103)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Internal compiler error (version 1.2-rc4 'Carnac' (298900 
f95d7bdecfceb327f9d201a1348397ed8a843843 by android-jack-
team@google.com)).
Warning: This may have produced partial or corrupted output.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

I am gettting these errors while compiling a compiling a rom with jack server. I am trying to compile AOSP RoM for My Device. 
Please help me to fix out this.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar error and Googling it sent me [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221708).

My machine has 4 processing cores but only 4GB of RAM, so I stipulated to only use -Xmx3g on my exported ANDROID_JACK_VM_ARGS variable as well as editing my ~/.jack-server/config.properties file to reduce the max-service parameter from 4 to 1.

Maybe try these changes and see if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Create a 15G swapfile. Google instructions how to do it on Linux...

Oops, this is internal compiler error. You either interrupted the build, which resulted in corruption or a previous out of memory situation did the same. The best resolution is to do make clobber or make clean and start from the beginning. You may also try to manually delete the java intermediates Jack was building, but I prefer the former.Make a swapfile first...